# Interpretation of sums using $\cdots$

Tags: summation, notation

Consider the sum
$$\sum_{1\le k_1 < k_2 < \cdots < k_r \le n}k_1k_2\ldots k_r$$

Does this simply mean
$$\sum_{\substack{|K|=r}\\\inf(K)\ge 1\\\sup(K)\le n}\prod_{k\in K} k$$

I am specifically worried about the situation when $n=r=0$. In the second notation, this is clearly 1, but I'm not sure if it is 0 or 1 in the first notation.

Comment: It would need clarification for the specific situation, but an empty product usually $=1$. In passing, I would say you are overloading the second expression; set $K$ could be defined separately.

Comment: @Joffan I don't understand your second sentence at all. The only overloading I know of is using the same symbol to mean multiple things, but I don't think I have done that here. What do you mean by defining K separately?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{1 \leq k_1 \leq k_2 \cdots \leq k_{r-1} \leq k_r \leq n} k_1 k_2 \cdots k_{r-1} k_r = \sum_{ k_1=1}^{n} \sum_{ k_2=k_1}^{n} \cdots \sum_{ k_{r-1}=k_{r-2}}^{n} \sum_{ k_r=k_{r-1}}^{n} k_1 k_2 \cdots k_{r-1} k_r
\end{eqnarray*}
This sum will become more and more difficult as you do each one & will relate to the Bernoulli numbers. I am not sure if there is a neat closed form for it.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit That is not the sum I am looking at, but it illustrates the same question. I am looking for advice on how to interpret it, not solve it. What happens when $n$ and $r$ are 0? (If you are curious, your sum does have a neat closed form)

Comment: Sorry just spotted the $<$'s not $\leq$'s (I will buy some glasses) ... what is the closed form for my misunderstanding ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I don't know yet. Finding one is an exercise in a book I am working through. An answer is provided, but I don't want to look at it before attempting the problem. I will probably put it here in a couple of days.

Comment: @eigensheep I misunderstood slightly, my apologies, but I still think there could be a simpler way to express it - perhaps $$\sum_{r\text{-combinations}\\\text{ from }[1,n]=:K}\prod^r k_i$$but it will end up being a matter of taste no doubt. :-)

Comment: Your second expression is fine ... you want the sum to go over elements of the power set $2^{[n]}$ that are of cardinality $r$ and then take the product of the elements in each set. I get the feeling both problems will have closed forms.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit They do. But "I am specifically worried about the situation when n=r=0. In the second notation, this is clearly 1, but I'm not sure if it is 0 or 1 in the first notation."

Comment: @eigensheep It is $1$ in the first notation as well. In both cases, it is an empty product and those are always $1$. (Although I admit that it feels more unintuitive when written with dots.)

Comment: @EikeSchulte Of course an empty product would be 1. I'm worried the sum may be empty.

Comment: @eigensheep Oh, I see. Let me try to add an answer then.

Comment: Empty products are 1, empty sums are 0, hence, when n=r=0, one gets an empty sum of empty products, that is, the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

I set out to write an answer that said that *clearly* the first notation gives $1$ as well but now I am not so sure anymore.

You are essentially defining the set $I = \{\,(k_1, \dots, k_r)\,\vert\,1 \leq k_1 < \dots < k_r \leq n\,\}$. I see three sensible ways to translate the condition $1 \leq k_1 < \dots < k_r \leq n$.

1. You can first split it into conditions for each $k_i$, i.e. $1 \leq k_1 < k_2$, $k_1 < k_2 < k_3$, $\cdots$, $k_{r-1} < k_r \leq n$ (and then split each of those into two inequalities). If you proceed like this, you don’t get any conditions in case $r = 0$, thus leaving you with the one-element set $\{()\}$ and a value of $1$.
2. Alternatively, you translate the condition directly as $1 \leq k_1$, $k_1 < k_2$, $\cdots$, $k_r \leq n$ which would give you $1 \leq n$ in case that $r = 0$ and thus $I$ would be empty if $n = 0$ as well.
3. You might also translate the condition as $1 \leq k_i$, $k_i \leq n$ for each $i$ and $k_1 < k_2$, $\cdots$, $k_{r-1} < k_r$. Treating the to relations on the outside differently doesn’t seem completely ridiculous, after all, it is a different relation. This would also give the value $1$.

It seems to me that the third interpretation is the correct one, but I really can’t give a better reason than that it agrees with your second notation which seems reasonable. If you want to use the first notation and the case $r = n = 0$ is important, you should probably mention which value you intend the sum to denote.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the empty sum is defined to be $0$ and the empty product is defined to be $1$.

> We find in *[Concrete Mathematics](http://www.matematica.net/portal/e-books/Graham%5C%20-%5C%20Knuth%5C%20-%5C%20Patashnik%5C%20-%5C%20%5C%20Concrete%5C%20Mathematics.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik in section 2.1:
>
> We write
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{P(k)}a_k\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   as an abbreviation for the sum of all terms $a_k$ such that $k$ is an integer satifying a given property $P(k)$. A *property* $P(k)$ is any statement about $k$ that can be either true of false. If $P(k)$ is false for all integers $k$, we have an **empty sum**; the value of an empty sum is defined to be zero.
>
> Considering OPs sum
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{1\le k_1 < k_2 < \cdots < k_r \le n}k_1k_2\ldots k_r\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   we observe according to (1) that if $n=0$, the sum is zero, *independent* of the setting of $r$. We do not need to care about the specific structure of the summands, when the sum is already an empty sum.

The summands of $(2)$ are finite products
\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=1}^r k_j\tag{3}
\end{align*}

We find in section 4.2 that the value of an **empty product** is by definition given as $1$. So, if $r=0$ the product in (3) is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum $\sum_{1\leq i < j \leq n}$ is merely a shorthand for $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n}\sum_{i<j\leq n}$. Hence
$$\sum_{1 \leq k_1 <k_2 < \dots < k_r \leq n} k_1k_2\dots k_r = \sum_{1\leq k_1 \leq n}\sum_{k_1 < k_2 \leq n}\dots \sum_{k_{r-1} < k_r \leq n}k_1k_2\dots k_r$$
Written like this the interpretation when $r=0$ is obvious: There is no sum operator, so $n=0$ cannot produce an empty sum. It is then clear that the two expressions in the question are equivalent.